# Elementary OS: boot ISO from USB using GRUB

Tags: grub, usb-drive

I'm trying to boot the latest ISO image of Elementary OS from my USB with GRUB.

I use the same GRUB configuration that I use with Ubuntu images, which works fine, and since Elementary is Ubuntu based, I thought it would work as well.

But I get the error:

```
(initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

To an extent, I understand this error, which I  sort out adding in the GRUB where to find the ISO image:

```
set root='(hd0,1)'
set iso_path=/elementaryos-5.1-stable.20191202.iso
loopback loop $iso_path

menuentry "Try or install elementary OS" {
 linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$iso_path maybe-ubiquity quiet splash
 initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

I tried with `findiso=$iso_path` which works on Debian, but the result is the same. What other GRUB configurations could I try? I prefer not to unpack the ISO to make things work.

I check the mdsum of the ISO, it's OK.

Comment: It seems that within the initrd.lz I couldn't find the logic for looking up the iso. Maybe that's why?

Comment: Try rebooting few times...I don't know why, but sometimes ISO from usb doesn't work and sometimes does...

Answer (score 1):

The easy fix is to create a folder named **/casper** on the root of your USB drive and copy **filesystem.squashfs** into that folder. It seems that they changed how the boot process is working between 5.0 and 5.1. 
*Caveat, I've only tested this with the default install of glim, but it should work fine.   (github.com/thias/glim)*

Shawn

issue:  Appears to be that ***/casper*** is hard coded and/or not respecting the $root/$loop variable(s). Probably is related to the recent switch towards using a pure Debian Live-build.  Lot's has changed since the prior build

https://github.com/elementary/os/wiki/Building-iso-Images

Answer (score 0):

#### Partial solution:

Using the `vmlinuz` and `initrd` from an  Ubuntu ISO, I could boot Eos.

Comment: Which version of elementary did you use? Version 5.1 is different to 5.0, as I can boot 5.0 with default GRUB config from GLIM Multiboot Maker, but not with 5.1.

Comment: @AdeMalsasaAkbar I'm using 5.1

Comment: how did you do it? You copied vmlinuz file from existing Ubuntu ISO into elementary 5.1 ISO? Or something different? I want to make a working multiboot USB to ship it to friend in other island.

Comment: @AdeMalsasaAkbar I copied *vmlinuz* and  *initrd* into the usb, the location could be any, I just put them in a folder called *eos*. Then int the *grub.cfg* I changed the parameters **linux** and **initrd**: `linux /eos/vmlinuz` and `initrd /eos/initrd`. If you have any doubt I can extend my answer explaining my grub configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza Rufus para bootear.

Sigue los siguientes pasos:

https://elementary.io/docs/installation#creating-an-installation-medium

Comment: Thanks. It's not about getting *any* bootable USB, but having one using GRUB. For rufus you need windows, which is what I want to avoid.